# Is it common for US states to pass resolutions supporting federal legislation?

Tags: united-states, congress, state-legislatures

Is it common for US state legislatures to pass resolutions officially supporting bills in Congress? Does Congress give such resolutions significant weight?

Comment: Is there some context? For example is there a particular piece of legislation that you are thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

In our federated constitutional republic states endorsing or not endorsing federal laws is not common, and it's irrelevant.  The federal legislature has it's own independent scope, and per the Constitution article 10, everything else is left to the state and then the people, although there are exceptions when the courts get involved.

However not exactly to your point, sources for proposing new laws are not limited by the Constitution.  Generally these sources are congressional members, but individuals have a 1st amendment right to petition members for new legislation.  Likewise and more to your point, state legislatures may also propose new federal legislation and pass state resolutions to try to make their appeal more persuasive to Congress, in the hopes they will pursue it.

> [How Our Laws Are Made](https://www.congress.gov/help/learn-about-the-legislative-process/how-our-laws-are-made?)
> Similarly, state legislatures may ‘‘memorialize’’ Congress to enact specified federal laws by passing resolutions to be transmitted to the House and Senate as memorials. If favorably impressed by the idea, a Member may introduce the proposal in the form in which it has been submitted or may redraft it. In any event, a Member may consult with the Legislative Counsel of the House or the Senate to frame the ideas in suitable legislative language and form.

Comment: The only exceptions to their irrelevance involve proposals for or ratifications of constitutional amendments or conventions; petitions for interstate or international compacts (which must be approved by Congress); and adjustments of state boundary lines or subdivisions of states (which must be approved by Congress).

Comment: A reference to Nullification and its history might be a good reference, as a reader may want to go there next

Comment: @ohwilleke that's true in the purest sense of the word "endorsement."  But more generally, of course, there are various mechanisms under which state legislatures have to pass laws to concede to the Federal legislature in order to receive Federal legislations' benefits (highway funds and such).  By conceding to the legislative intent of those Federal laws, the state legislatures give lay observers the impression of endorsing those Federal laws.

Comment: It may be conceding, but using that term is misleading. The federal government may incentivse state governments, such that they benefit from making rules the federal government wants. It may be argued that the federal is forcing the state via the incentives, but that's a political argument.

Comment: In any area where the federal government is empowered to directly make law, though, the State is not empowered to nullify. That is a very clearly answered question, legally.